# C++/CLI project in C# solution usage

Tags: dll, .net-core, native

Maybe this header isn't decribe my problem exactly, but...
I have .NET Core console app project which uses C++/CLI project written as a wrapper for native C++ code from same dll.
So, both C# and C++/CLI project are compiled well, but when I run C# project, I get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualC.STLCLR, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I checked this file on my disk - I have it installed in many directories on it. I wrote all paths I've found in the PATH enviroment variable, but no effect.

My configuration:
Windows Server 2016, .NET Core 3.1.102, MSVS 2019 16.4.3.

Please, can someone say me the reason of this error and give me a correct solution? Thnxs. 
P.S. IF it needs I can add classes and data I use in my code.

P.P.S. I have it works under .NET Framework 4.8, but not .NET Core 3.1

Comment: Process Monitor should tell you which are the paths this program tries to find that assembly.

Comment: @Lex Li, pls, could you explain me this? Thnxs

Comment: If you never know that tool, learn it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: @Lex Li, I've checked logs from ProcMon, but no links on this library were found. It's strange - I have my code works well under .NET Framework 4.8, but not under .NET Core 3.1

Comment: This assembly is normally installed in the GAC, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualC.STLCLR.  But .NETCore no longer uses the GAC, so it can't be found.  You'll have to copy it into the build directory yourself.

Comment: The version number is odd btw, v2.0.0.0 is located in the old GAC, the directory name is C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualC.STLCLR\1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Rebuilding the DLL might well be advisable.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I've tried but still with no effect - I put `STLCLR` dll in all directories connected with projects in this solution. But, I haven't 1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a, just only v4.0_2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a directory... Is it correct that I should to find any solutions for loading GAC libraries on .NET Core? Thank you!

Comment: The old GAC is hidden from view.  Google "unregister shfusion.dll" to find out how to reveal its content.

Comment: @Hans Passant, thnx, it works, but now I have troubles with code running: well-working code on .NET 4.8 throw an exception under .net core 3.1 - mismatch definition method and it signature mismatch on C++/CLI clr types (for example, on List<MySameStruct ^> ). Has .net core 3.1 some new c++/cli features? I found one of your article about c++/cli in .net core - could you give me some link for actual c++/cli description? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded Microsoft.VisualC.STLCLR dll from
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL
and I put it on my repository and references it on my .net core project it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same error while migrating from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6.
I tried to copy the dll side by side with my binaries but with no success.
Procmon did not even list any read of the DLL (I am an happy user of Procmon for many years).

To bypass the runtime error, I removed uses of the cliext namespace in our C++/CLI code.
In my case, I had to convert code depending on :

```
#include <cliext\set>
#include <cliext\functional>
#include <cliext\vector>
#include <cliext\algorithm>
```

The exception occured after a call to a method which was using one of the cliext container.

By chance, the amount of conversion work was minimal.